# php dropdown box

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a airport database, I have a webpage that currently displays all my results in a table, 
 I have created a dropdown box so that I can refine the results by flight no, I can get the flight numbers to populate, but it does not seem to apply to the page when I submit, I followed the examples by my lecture, but still can't get it to work. Any advice would be appreciated! =]  attached is my code and a screenshot of what it currently looks like. [Airport DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSWgQ.png)

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'flight' ] ) ) 
{
    $flightNO = $_POST[ 'flight' ];
} else 
{
    $flightNO = null;
}

$connect = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "" );
mysqli_select_db( $connect, "airportdb" );

?>

<!-- Form --> 
<section id="two" class="wrapper style3">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 align="center">Welcome to Dublin Airport Flight Information Helpdesk</h2>
        <div class="container 50%" align="center">
            <!-- Dropdown Box -->
            <!-- Query -->
            <?php
            $result = mysqli_query( $connect, "select flight from arrivals" );
            ?>
            <form action="arrivals.php" method="post">
                <div class="row uniform" align="center">
                    <div class="6u 12u$(small)">
                        <div class="select-wrapper">
                            <select name="flight">
                                <option value="All">- All -</option>
                                <?php
                                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
                                    echo '<option value ="' . $row[ 'flight' ] . ">" . $row[ 'flight' ] . '</option>';

                                }
                                echo '</select>';
                                ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="6u 12u$(small)">
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li><input value="Find" class="special" type="submit">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<!-- Table -->
<section id="three" class=" wrapper style2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">

            <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['flight']))
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from arrivals where flight='$flightNO'");
                else
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from arrivals");

                echo '<h4>Flight Information for '.date('l d F Y'). ', '. date('h:i:s a'). '</h4>';     
                echo '<hr>';
                echo'<table>';
                echo '<thread>
                            <tr>
                                <th><font size="+1">Terminal</th>
                                <th><font size="+1">Origin</th>
                                <th><font size="+1">Airline</th>
                                <th><font size="+1">Flight No</th>
                                <th><font size="+1">Scheduled Date</th>
                                <th><font size="+1">Scheduled Time</th>
                                <th><font size="+1">Status</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>';

                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo '<tbody align="left">';
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['terminal'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['origin'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['airline'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['flight'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['scheduledDate'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['scheduledTime'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</tbody>';
                }

                echo '</table>';
                mysqli_close($connect);

            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--end table php -->
```

Comment: You're missing a quotation mark when populating the select field: `echo '<option value ="' . $row[ 'flight' ] . "'>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saerdn was close with the comment, but the whole line is a bit off with your different quotation mark types:

You have:

```
echo '<option value ="' . $row[ 'flight' ] . ">" . $row[ 'flight' ] . '</option>';
```

What you should have is:

```
echo '<option value ="' . $row[ 'flight' ] . '">' . $row[ 'flight' ] . '</option>';
```

Comment: ah! thank you =]  tried it and works :)  didn't even notice it, such a silly mistake to do!

Comment: No problem. If that fixed everything, can you accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
if(!empty($flightNO))
```

instead of

```
if(isset($_POST['flight']))
```

also in order to debug,try

```
var_dump($flightNO);
```

at the end of the first if/else statement and see what's inside.